# Can I have NavigationLock apply to the parent component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I had this idea that I create a component ConfirmNavigation.razor:

```
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="@HasUnsavedChanges"
                OnBeforeInternalNavigation="OnBeforeInternalNavigation" />
```

with ConfirmNavigation.razor.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace LouisHowe.web.Shared
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Asks the user to confirm a navigation to another page if the page on has unsaved changes.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ConfirmNavigation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The MessageBoxPopup that is in MainLayout for notifying the user of issues.
        /// </summary>
        [CascadingParameter]
        private PopupMessageBox PopupMessageBox { get; set; } = default!;

        /// <summary>
        /// true if the page has unsaved changes. If so, will ask the user if they want to leave the page.
        /// This must be bound to the parent page's HasUnsavedChanges property.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        [Parameter]
        public bool HasUnsavedChanges { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<bool> HasUnsavedChangesChanged { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(PopupMessageBox);
            return base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }

        private async Task OnBeforeInternalNavigation(LocationChangingContext context)
        {
            if (!HasUnsavedChanges)
                return;

            // if the click Yes then we want to leave the page. 
            // we need to mark HasUnsavedChanges as false so we don't get asked again.
            if (await PopupMessageBox.Show("Leave Page",
                    "Do you wish to discard the changes you have made?<br/>" +
                    "Select No to stay on this page.<br/>" +
                    "Select Yes to go to the new page you selected",
                    PopupMessageBox.ButtonNo, PopupMessageBox.ButtonYes) == PopupMessageBox.ButtonYes)
            {
                HasUnsavedChanges = false;
                // gives the browser time to update the bound values
                await Task.Yield();
            }
            else
                context.PreventNavigation();
        }
    }
}
```

And then all I need to do in each razor page is add this at the bottom:

```
<ConfirmNavigation @bind-HasUnsavedChanges="@HasUnsavedChanges"></ConfirmNavigation>
```

But it doesn't work. My guess is that it confirms navigation in relation to the component it is in, but not the parent. Is there a way to make this work?

If not, it's not a biggie. It is just an easy way to not have to repeat this code page after page.

Comment: I believe this functionality is coming in Blazor 8.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a render problem.  `HasUnsavedChanges` is only updating in the component when it's re-rendered by a parent render.  It's a value type.  If you were to change `HasUnsavedChanges` to a reference type object then `ConfirmNavigation` would have access to the current state, not that at the last render event.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis doesn't `bind-` make it essentially a reference variable?

Comment: No it doesn't.  if it's a `bool` true or false is passed, not a reference to the bool variable you assigned to the Parameter.  Anyway I checked and it is a rendering issue.  I've posted an answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your state changes you need to ensure you render the parent component.

Here's a demo that shows both with and without a render [calling StateHasChanged].

**Confirm Navigation**

```cs
<PopUp @ref=_popUp />
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="@HasUnsavedChanges"
                OnBeforeInternalNavigation="OnBeforeInternalNavigation" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>HasUnsavedChanges : @HasUnsavedChanges</pre>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool HasUnsavedChanges { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Show { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> HasUnsavedChangesChanged { get; set; }

    private PopUp? _popUp;
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private async Task OnBeforeInternalNavigation(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        if (!HasUnsavedChanges)
            return;

        if (_popUp is not null)
        {
            var result = await _popUp.OpenAsync("Are You Sure Mate!");
            if (!result)
                context.PreventNavigation();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index**

```cs
@page "/"
@implements IHandleEvent

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<ConfirmNavigation HasUnsavedChanges=_isDirty />

<div class="p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.ChangeStateWithRender>Change State with Render</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.ChangeState>Change State without Render</button>
</div>

<div class="alert @(_isDirty? "alert-danger" : "alert-success")">
    @( _isDirty ? "Dirty" : "Clean")
</div>

@code {
    private Boolean _isDirty = false;


    private void ChangeState()
        => _isDirty = !_isDirty;


    private void ChangeStateWithRender()
    {
        _isDirty = !_isDirty;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    // Replaces the double render UI Event hander with one that just executes the registered Handler
    // i.e. no automatic StateHasChanged
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
        => item.InvokeAsync(obj);
}
```

My quick and dirty popup:

```cs
@if (_show)
{
    <div class="bg-light border border-dark m-3">
        <div class="m-2">@_message</div>
        <div class="p-2">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.ReturnExit>Exit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.ReturnCancel>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool>? _taskCompletionSource;
    private Task<bool> _runningTask = Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
    private string _message = "Are You Sure?";
    private bool _show;

    public Task<bool> OpenAsync(string message)
    {
        if (_runningTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            _message = message;
            _show = true;
            _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            _runningTask = _taskCompletionSource.Task;
            this.StateHasChanged();
            return _runningTask;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
    private void ReturnExit()
    {
        _show = false;
        _taskCompletionSource?.SetResult(true);
    }

    private void ReturnCancel()
    {
        _show = false;
        _taskCompletionSource?.SetResult(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the above. Question 1: What is the purpose of 'IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync'? I added it to my razor file code and get a compiler error of: CampaignPage.IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem, object?)': containing type does not implement interface 'IHandleEvent'

Comment: Question 2: you have `HasUnsavedChanges=_isDirty` which works. But I thought it should be `HasUnsavedChanges="@_isDirty"` - what is the difference between the two syntaxes?

Comment: Question 3: The key change you made was to remove `[BindProperty]` and make it `HasUnsavedChanges=HasUnsavedChanges` instead of `@bind-HasUnsavedChanges="@HasUnsavedChanges"`. I take it this is your "When your state changes you need to ensure you render the parent component" but how does that setting cause the parent to render?

Comment: Question 4: I assume the `<pre>HasUnsavedChanges : @HasUnsavedChanges</pre>` was just for debugging as removing it still works. (I had thought at first this was what caused the parent to render.) Is that correct? (BTW - I ask these questions because I want to understand why, not just take something that works and use it blindly. Asking is the only way I'll get close to the level of you and @HH.)

Comment: @DavidThielen - I don't mind at all.  I'll add a second answer to this question to answer all your questions in a while.

Answer (score 1):

1 **IHandleEvent**

`IHandleEvent` is an interface that components can implement.  If a component implements `IHandleEvent`, the Renderer calls 'IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync' rather that the event handler itself.

`ComponentBase` registers the following handler:

```cs
async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
{
    var uiTask = item.InvokeAsync(obj);

    var isCompleted = uiTask.IsCompleted || uiTask.IsCanceled;

    if (!isCompleted)
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
        await uiTask;
    }

    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

It renders if `item` [the actual event handler such as a button click handler] yields and then renders at the completion of the handler.

In the example I've added the following handler to ensure no rendering takes place.  It overrides the default `ComponentBase` implementation as I want no automatic calls to `StateHasChanged`: I want to call them manually to demonstrate the effect.  You shouldn't use it.

```cs
Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
        => item.InvokeAsync(obj);
```

2 **Nomenclature in Component Declarations**

You only need to do `HasUnsavedChanges="@_isDirty"` if `HasUnsavedChanges` is a string.  Otherwise the Razor interpreter understands what you want and generates the correct `RenderTreeBuilder` attribute instructions.  It's personal coding style, like I always use `this`.

3 **Bind Property**

I've explained binding in an answer to another question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76451885/13065781.  In this case there's no need to pass the pass the value back to the parent.  If you cancel navigation, you don't change the value, if you navigate, there's no point.

Seting the properrty in the parent doesn't cause the parent to render.  It's the activity that sets it that will.  For example clicking a button to set it, or setting a value in the parent through an EventCallback in an input control [ValueChanged].  In `ComponentBase` all UI events , including EventCallbacks, are handled by the registered `IHandleEvent`.

4 **Debug Output**

Correct.

Comment: This helps me understand better - thanks

Comment: Good point that changing a property doesn't cause any action, rendering or otherwise. It's at the completion of an activity that it then looks to see what's changed, if anything. And if something has changed, re-render anything using the propert(ies) that changed - correct?