# What's the difference between @bind-Data vs. ref.DataChanged(data)?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

If I need to update the data in a child component from the parent I can do:

```
<OrganizationGrid @bind-Data="@Values"/>
```

Or I can do:

```
<OrganizationGrid @ref="OrgGrid"/>
```

And then call:

```
OrdGrid.ValuesChanged(Values);
```

Is there any difference between the two? Or any trade-offs of one approach vs. the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding is Razor, not C#.  The Razor compiler turns any bind into a setter and getter using `Value` and `ValueChanged` [if your using `Value` as you parameter name].

Your example suggests you're only one way binding.  If so, just use the Parameter name `Value=Values`.

In `<OrganizationGrid @Data="@Values"/>` whenever the parent component renders, the Renderer will do an update check on the `ParameterView` object it holds for the component.  If it detects a change it will call `SetParametersAsync` and pass in the updated `ParameterView` instance.  The component renders based on the mutated state.

With `OrdGrid.ValuesChanged(Values);` you are calling a method.  This may mutate the state of the component, but unless you trigger a render (by calling StateHasChanged), the changes won't be reflected in the UI.

Comment: So `@bind-Value=` is functionally equivalent to `Value=` and `ValueChanged=` both being set/handled? And so, in the case of `@bind-Value=`, that means I need to declare and implement `ValueChanged(data)` because I need to se the new value when the data is changed. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  See my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Blazor old timers we call bind the bind triumverate: any component that implements bind needs to implement `Value`, `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression`.

Here's a very simple example:

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.Increment>Increment from @this.Counter</button>
</div>

@code {
    // These are what we call the Bind Triumverate
    // In this case we don't use ValueExpression 
    // but it's often used to get the FieldIdentifier for EditContext operations
    // or in a composite component to get the validation messages
    [Parameter]public int Counter { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> CounterChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<object>>? CounterExpression { get; set; }


    private async Task Increment()
    {
        await CounterChanged.InvokeAsync(this.Counter + 1);
    }
}
```

The demo page using this:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<Component @bind-Counter=_counter />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Counter: @_counter</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private int _counter;
}
```

When this code gets compiled into C# code by the Razor compiler what you get is [I've abbreviated it a bit by taking out the type checking]:

```cs
__builder.OpenComponent<SO76447597.Pages.Component>(5);
__builder.AddAttribute(6, "Counter",_counter));
__builder.AddAttribute(7, "CounterChanged", CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => _counter = __value, _counter))));
__builder.AddAttribute(8, "CounterExpression", (() => _counter));
```

To  see the compiled code: https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/0a487f4d0970267f871bea5ef77e4e42